# Appending QueryString on Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to Append to the QueryString on Postback? If it is, how in the world do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean after the page has posted back?  Or, before the Page starts the post?

Comment: What is your goal? Usually you'd just store whatever data you're looking for somewhere in a FORM - like a hidden input. You could Response.Redirect if you need to change the URL or use javascript to do it if it's for bookmarking purposes.

Comment: that worked perfectly. forgot to think about doing it the straightforward way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. You don't have a lot of control over postbacks with ASP.NET. For another type of application, you could post to another page. I know there is a mechanism to post to another page in asp.net-- but I've never had the need to do it.

What are you trying to accomplish-- perhaps there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `Response.Redirect()`:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?querystring=value", Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath));
```

However, I don't think it's possible to attach a query string to a URL without fully reloading the page again.

A query string in a URL is not like an anchor. It can have an effect server side and is classed as a different URL from one without a query string. Therefore, it's not possible to attach a query string without the page reloading.

Comment: At the end of a method which is actioned on PostBack

Comment: Thanks, Curt! The only problem is I can't use Response.Redirect. Any way to do it without that?

Comment: Why can't you use `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: Because everything is on one page with a lot of hidden panels that become visible. If I use Response.Redirect it basically starts everything fresh as if the page was first loaded.

Comment: What about `Server.Transfer`?

Comment: I'm saving the SessionId in the QueryString, so if the user times out the session I can pick the id up from the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are going to another page then you can use response.redirect("page path" + query string)to append your query string.
2. If you are on the same page and you want to do it on some button click, which is already   posting the page, then you can use the
   postbackurl property of the button and give the url of same page and
   append the query string there, So as the button was already posting
   the page, "PostbackUrl" wont post it again but it will modify the
   url (Now having your updated query string).

Following is Example of doing it on html page but you can do it using code also.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibRestrictAcct" runat="server"
   AlternateText="Restrict Account"  OnClick="ibRestrictAcct_Click"
   PostBackUrl="~/MyPage.aspx?Action=Restrict" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this (if you dont redirect) ?

```
 Request.QueryString.Add("Name","Value");
```

Comment: another guy were having the same problem as you. maybe his solution is better: http://forums.asp.net/t/1291000.aspx/2/10

Comment: Thanks! I saw that. Doesn't look like he really gives his solution though.